# using collection inside query for another subquery

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm writing a query like this:

```
var TheQuery = (from t in MyDC.Table1
                where ....
                select new SomeContainerModel()
                {
                    Collection1 = (from t2 in MyDC.Table2
                                   ....
                                   select new SomeModel()
                                   {
                                       SomeID = t2.SomeID
                                   }

                     Collection2 = (from x in Collection1
                                    from t3 in MyDC.Table3
                                    where x.SomeID == t3.SomeOtherID
```

What I want to do, is use the result of `Collection1` as an input for `Collection2`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `let` keyword to introduce new range variable for subquery result.

```
var theQuery = (from t in MyDC.Table1
                let subQuery = (from t2 in MyDC.Table2
                                ...
                                select new SomeModel() { SomeID = t2.SomeID })
                where ....                
                select new SomeContainerModel()
                {
                    Collection1 = subQuery,
                    Collection2 = (from x in subQuery
                                    from t3 in MyDC.Table3
                                    where x.SomeID == t3.SomeOtherID)
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Collection1 is incompatible with Collection2. You converted Collection1 into a model and can no longer be translated into SQL.

I recommend you to treat your queries as IQuerable. Only until the very end when you need to physically execute it and retrieve the data.

Imagine each query as Transact-SQL scripts, even when you join it with MyDC.Table3, you are really only just adding a subquery, something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table3 a,
FROM (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE....) as SubQuery 
WHERE a.SomeID == SubQuery.SomeOtherID
```

So, try using an Anonymous type instead of SomeModel();